# Loop hierarchy to root

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008

I need to loop a hierarchy down to the root.
Here is my table columns

1. Id
2. ParentId
3. Description

I think you understand the problem. Item with ParentId NULL is the root.

Example

- Id=1 ParentId=NULL Descripion=Root
- Id=2 ParentId=1 Descripion=Child for Id1

Could this be done using linq? Or any better with a sql query.

Comment: Are you saying you want to return an entire hierarchy for a specific item?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this on Sql Server may be the solution: 
4 example if we want to find root of Child1 recursively we can use

```
WITH n(ID, Description) AS 
   (SELECT ID, Description
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE Description = 'Child1'
        UNION ALL
    SELECT nplus1.ID, nplus1.Description
    FROM youTable as nplus1, n
    WHERE n.ID = nplus1.ParentID)
SELECT name FROM n
```

take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972%28SQL.90%29.aspx) 4 *WITH* keyword 
Same solution on Oracle server will be using

```
SELECT Description 
  FROM yourTable
  START WITH name = 'Child1'
  CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = ParentID
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to change (invert) your tree structure to make a node contain its children instead of referencing its parent, like this:

```
    class Node
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Node> Children { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Then it will be easy to "Flatten" the tree into an IEnumerable with an extension like this:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> FlattenedTree<T>(this T node, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> getter)
    {
        yield return node;
        var children = getter(node);
        if(children != null)
        {
            foreach (T child in children)
            {
                foreach (T relative in FlattenedTree(child, getter))
                {
                    yield return relative;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And you can use your tree in a linq like this:

```
    var descriptions = MyTreeStructure.FlattenedTree(x => x.Children).Select(x => x.Description);
```